# Feasibility of upgrading a recent bike from a mechanical to an electronic groupset

Tags: mechanical, shimano-di2

A frequently asked question on this site is doing a significant component upgrade on a older bike. The answer is invariably that it is either infeasible, uneconomical, or both.

Now that the road bike market is moving to electronic shifting, and many have
perfectly nice, *recent* frames equipped with technology, notably Bowden cables, that may thankfully be heading towards obsolescence, is upgrading from either of the 2x11 groupsets

```
2018: 105 R7000
2017: Ultegra R8000
```

to either of the 2x12 groupsets

```
2022: 105 R7100 Di2
2022: Ultegra R8100 Di2
```

generally feasible and/or economical?

##### Related

- A "downgrade": [Installing mechanical group set on "electronic only" frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/45916/48599)

##### Update

At the outset it appears that the upgrade is more or less mundane, but that one subtle issue is whether having a dedicated hole behind the FD mount, a
[hole](https://youtu.be/pfigqBQ_bk0?feature=shared&t=133)
that's available on "electronic-only frames", is necessary,

[image: hole behind mount]

and whether passing the cable
[through the mount](https://youtu.be/N46XQQR1aw4?feature=shared&t=312)
is always an option.

[image: thread cable through mount]

Comment: Mechanical shifting is certainly not heading into obsolesce any time soon, maybe except for a small sector of high performance bikes. Yes, even 105 or Deore is that from the view of vast majority of bikes sold on the planet.

Comment: The more I think about it, even a full Di2 12-speed swap probably doesn't cost more than a nice set of wheels which many people put on mid-tier bikes as an upgrade, in most cases for marginal gains or subjective things like better looks or ride feel. You won't get a faster bike but shifting will be consistent all the time and you don't have adjust derailleurs, if that is what you are looking for, it might be money well worth spent. Beyond that, very unlikely that you have to go electronic soon, Shimano has just release a 12-speed iteration of the "people's groupset", many more years to come.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Good point. I am thinking of a long time span, over which a decent bike frame should last—say 20 years. But regardless, I qualified the statement.

Comment: @Sam7919 There is no way mechanical shifting is gone outside of the high end bikes sector. And for current higher end mechanical bikes parts will still be available, even if from some alternative trickled-down series. You still can find parts for 40 years old racing bikes with freewheels. 20 years is not *that* much.

Comment: Why would anyone in good health put batteries on a bike? Electronic shifting defeats the purpose of a bike imo.

Comment: Anyone with an 11 speed 105 or Ultegra groupset they want to get rid of, I'll gladly take it off your hands ;)

Comment: @WornChain You're right. The worry about recharging will be a dread, but it's easier to accept for the sake of skipping cable-elongation-fright. But yes, just like some are very keen on manual transmission in cars (1% of the population in N.A, myself included), there must remain some who are keen on fully manual (i.e. mechanical) shifting on bikes.

Comment: @Sam7919 The beauty of bikes imo is their simplicity, low cost and easy repairs. Electronics usually ruin all that. Different horses for different courses I guess. Go for what you like no matter what other people say.

Comment: The invariable "not worth it" answer comes from one or two (prolific) mouths only. The economics change over time and are different regionally. Currently it's worth running the numbers as what you want is not easily available used and a new bike so equipped is much more expensive now than it might have been a few years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the technical feasibility:

- Note on brakes: most current electronic groupsets are provided for hydraulic disc brakes, so obviously, a frame designed for rim brakes won't work (Ultegra is for example offered for rim brakes, 105 not).
- Shimano: the frame needs to be compatible with Di2: the battery in the seat post/tube, so you need to be able to run the cables to the derailleurs (for disk brake brifters, the connection between the shifter and the derailleur is wireless, the rim brake brifters require an additional cable, thx @TerrySeidler for the clarification).
- SRAM/Campagnolo: batteries are on the derailleurs themselves, and the connection between the derailleur and the shifter is wireless, so no compatibility restriction for the derailleurs (but there could be an additional one for the freehub body)

On the economic feasibility, it's fairly subjective and should be evaluated on a case by case basis, as it depends on the bike and the price of the groupset (installation included). At current price, a groupset is still less expensive than a new midrange bike with mechanical derailleurs, so if you consider electronic as a must have and you are happy with the frame/wheels, that will be a more significant update than a new bike for less money.

But I don't think that mechanical groupsets are doomed outside the high-end road segment. Concern of obsolescence wouldn't be a valid reason to upgrade. Shimano released recently a mechanical 105 12s, and the new GRX 12s is mechanical only — so at the time of writing, high-end gravel bikes with double chainrings are still sold with the "old" 11-speed to have electronic shifting, while less expensive models have the new 12s. Campagnolo also has a strong mechanical offering.

On the MTB/flat bar side, Shimano didn't even release electronic shifting for the latest generation of MTB groupsets (Mx100). They however released recently new Di2 derailleurs but they placed them in the electric section of their website (MTB or utility), with the possibility of having automatic transmissions being the selling point. SRAM is however only offering electronic transmission on their upper offerings for MTBs.

Comment: Great answer, but I thought I'd add some things ;).  
  
(1) Shimano did release 12-speed Di2 MTB, but it's e-bike only ;-)  
  
and (2) The Di2 connection between shifter and derailleur is only wireless for disc brake bikes, it is still wired for rim brake bikes.

Comment: @TerrySeidler I thought I wrote (1), but it could have been clearer. I reworded, thanks for the remark (they also release a 11-speed Linkglide version of the same derailleur + a bunch of CUES Di2 derailleurs).